# Online availability of high-quality Russian launch/space videos?

Tags: russia

I am interested in videos of Russian space program, especially the older ones (old Soyuz launches, Soyuz docking with MIR, Leonov's spacewalk etc.). While NASA puts all their videos online in good quality, searching for the Russian space program usually yields low-quality rips from TV documentaries and the like.

Is there an online repository of Russian space videos in high quality?

My constraints:

- I can somewhat read Russian, but searching in Russian is difficult for me (I cannot efficiently "scan" the text neither write a good query)
- Free access is good, but I am willing to pay reasonable money

Comment: Can't give a general answer, but the IMAX movie Mission to Mir is available on youtube in high def: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNzk5WWp67Y It has some awesome footage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend you BBC's "Space Race". It is a 4-part documentary about the race to the Moon between America and the Soviet Union. The first part deals essentially with Nazi Germany and its V-2 rockets, the 2nd part with the first artificial satellite in orbit, the 3rd part with the first human in space and the 4th with the first man on the Moon.

It is a very detailed documentary where you can see the Sputnik launch, the launch of Soviet dogs (Laikas), Vostok and Voskhod missions, the Nedelin disaster as well as the Nositel N-1 disaster. I'm sure you will like it, and you can stream / download it from the net for free.

https://www.google.at/search?q=bbc+space+race&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXpsmH6qTeAhVNYlAKHX7FBswQ_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=631